# Gmail app in iphone ignores "font-size" of html mail and change it to 13px

Tags: html, gmail, smartphone

I built an HTML page (using Photoshop), that I fit to emails. When I copy it to Gmail, send it using a browser in my PC, and open the message, it looks OK. But when I try to open it through my Gmail App on my iPhone, it completely ignores the `style="font-size:11px"` and changes it back to 13px.

All style properties are inline and the page width is 600px.

What can I do in the HTML code to make it accept a smaller font?  I don't want to change the iPhone settings or something like that, because it should be send to other iPhones. And of course I don't want to ask them to change the settings.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a wiled guess, but you could try the markup that Gmail is using for "small" fonts, like this:

```
<font size="1">Text to be displayed with "small" font</font>
```

Let me know if it worked!